# Java Program Structure

Tags: java, inner-classes

I am building an app where I print a word in different languages based on a user's selection from a dropdown menu. My current method works however is not efficient as I am getting the data from a nested class and requesting it from a completely different class which requires a line of code for each word in a nested class. How can I achieve this in a more efficient/easier way? Here is the basic format of said code:

```
public class words {

   class example {
       String english = "example";
       String chinese = "example_in_chinese";
   }

   class example2 {
       String english = "example2";
       String chinese = "example2_in_chinese";
   }
}


public class getWords {

    words word = new words();
    words.example example = word.new example();
    words.example2 example2 = word.new example2();

    */ I have to repeat the above line for each of the 20 
    words I have in a nested class
    /*

}
```

Comment: Perhaps use a dictionary.  One way to implement a dictionary in Java is to use a `java.util.Map` to hold an English word as the key and a Chinese word as a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can try to use Map.

```
public class Words {
    static Map<String, String> example1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
    example1.put("english", "example");
    example1.put("chinese", "example_in_chinese");

    static Map<String, String> example2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
    example2.put("english", "example2");
    example2.put("chinese", "example2_in_chinese");
}
```

So you can just call

```
Words.example1.get("english");
```

Or even further, you can create an enum Language

```
enum Language {
    ENGLISH, CHINESE
}

public class Words {
    static Map<Language, String> example1 = new HashMap<Language, String>();
    example1.put(Language.ENGLISH, "example");
    example1.put(Language.CHINESE, "example_in_chinese");

    static Map<Language, String> example2 = new HashMap<Language, String>();
    example1.put(Language.ENGLISH, "example2");
    example1.put(Language.CHINESE, "example2_in_chinese");
}

Words.example1.get(Language.ENGLISH);
```

Just to reduce typing error possibility.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am now stuck on another problem. I have a JComboBox populated from a String Array however I need to associate those items with the items in the HashMap so I can call and print all the languages for a given word.

Example::
If user selects example1

Print example1.get("english");
Print example1.get("chinese");
etc...... for each language

Comment: I think you need to post it as a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use chain of responsibility design pattern to determine which language is appropriate to print.

It takes long to show with code but I will given hint to you.

Iterate over objects to find printable language with given dropdown value.
If you can not find appropriate language for printing then ignore it.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/chain_of_responsibility_pattern.htm

Comment: It sounds like the OP is a newbie in Java and talking about design patterns may confuse him/her more.